# Password recovery

Tags: password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative(root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)

I have Ubuntu 11.1 , do not remember setting it up with a password but, now it will not let me in without a password. Is there a default password? Can I retrieve a password? Can I change a password without knowing the old one?